# Details about attachments in corda

Tags: corda

According to the documentation [corda attachments](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html) working with attachments is a very simple task. But I could not find answers about next points:

- Where does attachment store? Is it a database, file system?
- Does corda have any limitation with attachment size "10-100mb"
- Any limits with attachment amount?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are stored in the node's database, in the `NODE_ATTACHMENTS` table.

There is no limit on the number or size of attachments in a transaction. However, each compatibility zone has a set of network parameters, one of which is `maxTransactionSize`. This specifies the maximum allowed size in bytes of a transaction, including its attachments.